# How to return false if collection is null before stream in java 8?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I wrote bellow code to check some condition.

```
/**
 * Returns true if any of the dose detail is an x
 * @return boolean
 */
public <DD extends BD<DI>, DI extends BI> boolean Y(final Collection<DD> dds) {
    return dds.stream().anyMatch(dd -> dd.M().K());
}
```

but this method have some risk dds , come as null. I need to return false is dd also null. how can be modify this method using java 8 to null safe ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or you can do like this. More or like the same way

```
return dds != null && dds.stream().anyMatch(dd -> dd.M().K());
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be as simple as

```
public <DD extends BD<DI>, DI extends BI> boolean Y(final Collection<DD> dds) {
    return dds == null ? false : dds.stream().anyMatch(dd -> dd.M().K());
}
```

Comment: You never need to combine literal `true` or `false` with another `boolean` expression; there’s always an alternative without it. Here, it’s just `return dds != null && dds.stream().anyMatch(dd -> dd.M().K());`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can wrap it around an `Optional` as:

```
public <DD extends BD<DI>, DI extends BI> boolean Y(final Collection<DD> dds) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(dds)
            .filter(d -> d.stream().anyMatch(dd -> dd.M().K()))
            .isPresent();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer from [@the_tech_maddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6487148/the-tech-maddy). Just a preferred way to check a collection is null or empty from `org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils`;

```
return CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(dds) && dds.stream().anyMatch(dd -> dd.M().K());
```